# How to get html data-attribute string from a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am constructing an html form in php with javascript and css, the following line of code works fine and displays a textarea with the required prefix:

`$form .= '<textarea class="text" data-prefix="Message from: " ></textarea>';`

However I want to include a php variable i.e

`$form .= '<textarea class="text" data-prefix="Message from: $foo" ></textarea>';`

This show the textarea with the prefix 'Message from $foo'.
How do I show it with the value of $foo combined into the data-prefix i.e 'Message from Foo'?

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to concat PHP variable with your string

```
$form .= '<textarea class="text" data-prefix="Message from: '.$foo.'" ></textarea>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
$form .= "<textarea class='text' data-prefix='Message from: " . $foo. "' ></textarea>";
```

or

```
$form .= "<textarea class='text' data-prefix='Message from: {$foo}' ></textarea>";
```